mPDF not loading custom Persian font correctly (BMitra, IRANSans, ...) for Farsi text
I'm having trouble getting mPDF to properly render Farsi (Persian) text using custom fonts like BMitra and IRANSans.
Problem:
The main issue is that when I try to generate a PDF with Farsi content, mPDF either fails to load the specified font, or the text appears in a different font altogether. Additionally, I tried enabling OpenType Layout (OTL) features like useOTL and useKashida, but I received an error stating that my font does not support OTL tables:
I attempted using the IRANSans font, but the issue persisted. Here is the relevant part of my PHP code:

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [__DIR__]),
    'format' => $PAGE_FORMAT,
    'autoLangToFont' => true,
    'mode' => 'utf-8',
    'useSubstitutions' => true,
    'fontdata' => $fontData +
        [
            'bmitra' => [
                'R' => 'assets/fonts/pdf/bmitra.ttf',
                'B' => 'assets/fonts/pdf/bmitrabd.ttf',
            ],
            'btitr' => [
                'R' => 'assets/fonts/pdf/btitr.ttf',
                'B' => 'assets/fonts/pdf/btitr.ttf'
            ],
            'iransans' => [
                'R' => 'assets/fonts/pdf/iransans.ttf',
                'B' => 'assets/fonts/pdf/iransans.ttf'
            ],
            'vazir' => [
                'R' => 'assets/fonts/pdf/vazir.ttf',
            ],
        ],
    'default_font' => 'bmitra',
]);
$mpdf->SetDirectionality('rtl');

$imagePath = ($draftArray['imageId'] == 1) ? 'assets/media/backgrounds/A4.min.png' : 'assets/media/backgrounds/A5.min.jpg';

$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->Image($imagePath, 0, 0, $mpdf->w, $mpdf->h, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false);


$headerNumber = '<div dir="rtl" style="text-align: left;">';
$headerNumber .= '<span style="font-family: iransans;">شماره: 123456</span><br>';
$headerNumber .= '<span style="font-family: iransans;">تاریخ: 123456</span><br>';
$headerNumber .= '<span style="font-family: iransans;">پیوست: دارد</span>';
$headerNumber .= '</div>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($headerNumber, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);

Setting default_font to BMitra and IRANSans: The text appears, but the font is not correctly applied.
Disabling OTL and Kashida: The font loads, but the text doesn't render properly (e.g., letters are disconnected or appear in the wrong format).
Using other fonts: I tried different Persian fonts like Vazir and Sahel, but encountered similar issues.
Testing paths and font file validity: The fonts are correctly located and functional.

fix on this on this : github
'useOTL' => 0xFF,
'useKashida' => 75,

like this :
'fontdata' => $fontData + [
                'vazir' => [
                    'R' => 'Vazirmatn-Regular.ttf',  // Regular font
                    'B' => 'Vazirmatn-Bold.ttf',
                    'I' => 'Vazirmatn-Light.ttf',
                    'useOTL' => 0xFF,
                    'useKashida' => 75,

                ]
            ],

